# Fatal error: Cannot declare class User, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, mysql, include, fatal-error

I checked a few topics, but I can't find a solution to my problem in any of them.

In Index.php i have defined in header of document

```
<?php
include_once('class/User.php');
}
```

(in class/User.php i've got a lot of PHP functions)

Also in index.php i've got includes like:

```
<?php include('components/head.inc.php'); 
include('components/navbar.inc.php'); 
include('components/leftsidebar.inc.php'); ?>
```

So in components/navbar.inc.php i decided to put echo function which is defined in class/User.php. After this it shows me "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fetchAll()" - but i defined it in user.php. So i decided to put include User.php in navbar.inc.php and it shows me next error like

> "Fatal error: Cannot declare class User, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\class\User.php on line 391" 391 line is end of document.

Function in user.php

```
function fetchAll($query){
    $con = new PDO(DBINFO, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $stmt = $con->query($query); 
    return $stmt->fetchAll(); 
}
```

and this in navbar.inc.php –

```
              <span><i data-feather="bell" class="svg-icon"></i></span>
              <?php
        $query = "SELECT * from `notifications` where `status` = 'unread' order by `date` DESC";
        if(count(fetchAll($query))>0){
        ?>
              <span class="badge badge-primary notify-no rounded-circle"><?php echo count(fetchAll($query)); ?></span>
              <?php
                 }
                     ?>
```

Comment: Did you `include` or `include_once` in `navbar`?

Comment: Are you positive that these files are all being included correctly?

Comment: @El_Vanja i did include in navbar.inc.php, and include once in index.php

Comment: So you're trying to include a class that was already included. Use `include_once` everywhere.

Comment: @El_Vanja I did it and it changed to Fatal  '"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fetchAll()"' but I have defined this function fetchAll in user.php and it looks like it can't get the definition from user.php

Comment: Can you please share how you're using the function and how it's defined?

Comment: If `User` is a class, and that function is *inside* the class, then you can't call it like a regular procedural function.

Comment: I would also recommend you to rethink how you handle database connections/queries. Looking at your "fetchAll"-function, it will create a new connection every time you call that function. That's an unnecessary overhead. You should only connect to the database once per request and reuse that connection. The same goes for the results. If you're using it for multiple things, store it and reuse it. Right now you're not just creating two connections, you also query the same exact data twice. If you just want to know the row count, query `SELECT count(*) ...` instead of fetching all results.